# How to add page specific java script in the Phalcon view

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to add page specific jquery/javascript to all the views in the of phtml views
How to do this in Phalcon?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just open the PHTML file and add the `script` tag. To add that in all pages, you have to find the PHTML file that is your master layout or the footer page and add it there

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos I think he wants to have a javascript file included in specific page only. For example having slider library only on pages containing slider etc...

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to include page specific assets.

**1)** Use **[Phalcon Assets Manager](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html)**

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Add some local CSS resources
        $this->assets->addCss("css/style.css");
        $this->assets->addCss("css/index.css");

        // And some local JavaScript resources
        $this->assets->addJs("js/jquery.js");
        $this->assets->addJs("js/bootstrap.min.js");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some amazing website</title>

        {{ assets.outputCss() }}
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        {{ assets.outputJs() }}
    </body>
<html>
```

**2)** Make a simple `for` loop in your template and pass filenames from specific actions in your controller.

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->view->specificJavascripts = ['someFile', 'otherFile']
    }
}
```

And in my `_footer` partial:

```
{% if specificJavascripts  is defined %}
    {% for script in specificJavascripts  %}
        <script src="{{ static_url('frontend/js/'~ script ~'.js') }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I personally prefer this variant, since I'm using my own npm modules to minify and babelize my assets.

Comment: Thank you...One more question other frameworks like Laravel in the template we can define a part for java script. In the page(ex: user.blade.php) when i write in that part inside the script tag its included to the template. In there any way like this for Phalcon. And isnt there a burden when managing static scripts from the controllers?

Comment: @AzmathIkram It is all a preference. There is no way that is better than other. If you handle your assets in the controllers you need to maintain them there. If you move that functionality in the views, you have to maintain them there. You can always create relevant partials that contain your respective javascript and inject them in any other template you require.